# Rotating a shape in the div while making another div stay in the same place

Tags: html, css

I have a diamond shape in one div with an image in it and there is a div with absolute positioned text. On hover, I want the diamond to spin, but not the text. Is it possible to achieve? I suppose I will have to change the HTML a bit.
Here are my attempts so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="rel">
  <div class="dn-diamond">
    <h4> Random text </h4>
      <div class="dn-diamond-img">
        <img src="../images/someImage.png" alt="">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rel {
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}

.rel:hover {
    animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotateY(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}


.rel:hover .dn-diamond h4 {
    -webkit-animation-name: none !important;
  animation-name: none !important;
}

.dn-diamond h4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
}

.dn-diamond-img {
    width: 420px;
  height: 420px;

}

.dn-diamond-img img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-95px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-100px) translateY(45px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You're rotating the parent div (.rel:hover) when it seems like you only need to be rotating the image or it's parent div.

Comment: You have several answers. If any of them is ok for you, you should uovote/accept it. Otherwise, help them help you commenting what you don't like about the answers

Answer (score 1):

I not sure if you are looking for this:

http://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/qdrvgM

My changes

```
.rel {
    position: relative;

}

.rel:hover img{
    animation: spin 3s infinite linear;
}
```

And as well the animation, because don´t make sense for me the jump

```
@keyframes spin {
    from { 
      transform: rotate(45deg) translateX(-100px) translateY(45px);
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
    to { 
      transform: rotate(405deg) translateX(-100px) translateY(45px);
      transform-origin: 50% 50%; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any luck with the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I wanted the diamond to spin in 3d, so around its own axis

Answer (score 1):

You refer to it as a diamond, so I assume you want to keep it upright. I think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/t67c7ffq/1/

All I did was change `.rel:hover` to `.dn-diamond-img:hover`. This won't spin the `h4`.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it still rotates the image in undesired direction :-(

Answer (score 0):

Assign an `id=myimage` to your html `<img src="../images/someImage.png" alt="" id="myimage">`and then change the css from `.rel` to `#myimage`.  You only need to spin the image, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It unfortunately still does not work